# Is the purpose of an internal resistor in a practical voltage source to set the maximum possible current that can be drawn?

Tags: voltage, voltage-source

Going off the example circuit I attached below, is the purpose of an internal resistor to limit the maximum current that the voltage source can output? Since adding any passive component in series with the internal resistor would just reduce the current.

[image]

Comment: This resistor is not a real resistor. It is "model resistor" was added on purpose to include the real-world voltage source cannot provide an infinite amount of current. Also, models the "voltage drop effect". The Source voltage drops when the external load resistance is connected across the voltage source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not there purposely to reduce current, it is a parasitic effect.

If you look at a battery, it does not contain a separate resistor, it is just the structure and chemistry of the battery that causes internal series resistance.

Or a transformer, it also does not contain a separate resistance, it is the resistance of the copper coil itself.